How to prepare a cluster state $\frac12(|0000\rangle+|0110\rangle+|1001\rangle-|1111\rangle)$ in Qiskit?
Build the circuit in Qiskit, cluster state.

Hit the first and second qubits with the Hadamard, to get
\begin{align}
|0000\rangle + |0100\rangle + |1000\rangle + |1100\rangle \tag1
\end{align}
where we neglect normalization. Next, apply the controlled-Z gate to the first two qubits to obtain
\begin{align}
|0000\rangle + |0100\rangle + |1000\rangle - |1100\rangle. \tag2
\end{align}
Finally, apply controlled-NOT between the first and fourth as well as between the second and third qubits to get
\begin{align}
|0000\rangle + |0110\rangle + |1001\rangle - |1111\rangle \tag3
\end{align}
which is the desired state. Consult qiskit's excellent online documentation, such as this one or this one to find the APIs corresponding to the Hadamard, controlled-Z, and controlled-NOT gates.

thank you very much！！！
